# How to create a column in the existing dataframe with independent row values

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe like this in pandas DataFrame where `A` is the column name:

```
results.head()
A
when you are away 
when I was away
when they are away
```

I want to add a new column B which would seem like the following:

```
A                   B
when you are away   you
when I was away     I
when they are away  they
```

I tried with this code but it did not work:

```
results.assign(B = you, I, they)
```

I am new to pandas dataframe and would very much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
B_list = ['you','I','they']
results['B'] = B_list
```

OR

```
results = results.assign(B=['you', 'I', 'they'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in placing the column in a specific location (index), then use the insert method:

```
results.insert(index, "ColName" , new_set)
```

otherwise, the answer by Mayank is simpler.